# How can I join more than two streaming datasets in PySpark while maintaining the 'null' values?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am trying to join more than two streaming datasets in PySpark using the following steps:

1. Watermarking a dataset using the following code:

```py
watermark = '1 second'
df_watermarked = df.withWatermark("timestamp", watermark)
```

2. Preparing a dataset to join on using the following code:

```py
unigue_ids = df_watermarked.dropDuplicates(
            ["some_id", "timestamp"]
        ).select("some_id", "timestamp")
```

3. Preparing datasets to be joined using the following code:

```py
df_a = df_watermarked.where(F.col("some_parameter") == "A").alias("A")
df_r = df_watermarked.where(F.col("some_parameter") == "R").alias("R")
df_i = df_watermarked.where(F.col("some_parameter") == "I").alias("I")
```

4 Performing the actual join using the following code:

```py
def get_join_str(some_parameter):
  return f"""left.some_id = {some_parameter}.some_id 
          AND {some_parameter}.timestamp BETWEEN left.timestamp 
          AND left.timestamp + interval 1 second """

df = unigue_ids.alias("left") \
.join(df_b, F.expr(get_join_str("B")), how="leftOuter") \
.select('some_id', 'timestamp', 'some_parameter')
```

output:

```py
+--------------+---------+---------------------+
|some_id      |timestamp       |some_parameter|
+--------------+---------+----------------------+
|    74C8090008| 20230110111223|          null|
|    74D51F0008| 20230110111223|             B|
|    74D1010008| 20230110111224|          null|
```

The problem is that if I do more than one join, I lose the 'null' values. For example:

```py
def get_join_str(some_parameter):
  return f"""left.networkcallref = {some_parameter}.networkcallref 
          AND {some_parameter}.timestamp BETWEEN left.timestamp 
          AND left.timestamp + interval 1 second """

df = unigue_ids.alias("left") \
.join(df_b, F.expr(get_join_str("B")), how="leftOuter") 

df = df.join(df_a, F.expr(get_join_str("A")), how="leftOuter") \
.select('some_id', 'timestamp', 'some_parameter')
```

Output:

```py
+--------------+---------+---------------------+
|some_id      |timestamp       |some_parameter|
+--------------+---------+----------------------+
|    74D51F0008| 20230110111223|             B|
```

The output is missing the 'null' values. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how I can maintain the 'null' values when joining multiple datasets?